# Size of my char array automatically shrinks to 1 after calling a function

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion, c-strings, function-declaration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void getinput(char &first,char &second);
 
//char getinput(char &first,char &second);
 
int main()
{
char a[60],b[60];
getinput(a[60],b[60]);

cout << a[60] << "   l     " << b[60] <<endl;

}

void getinput (char &first, char &second){
    
    cout << "Enter First Input: ";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Enter Second Input: ";
    cin >> second; 
    cout << "You Entered " << first << " and " << second <<endl;
    
}
```

Everytime i try and make the size of my char arrays bigger so when i call the get input function s0 i can input more then one character is automatically shrinks down in size to one character.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: When you write `char a[60]`, `a` becomes an array of size `60`. But every time you write `a[60]` *after that*, you're accessing the array out of bounds (the last element is `a[59]`).

Comment: *Everytime i try and make the size of my char arrays bigger* -- *automatically shrinks down in size to one character.* -- Arrays are fixed in size and cannot be resized.

Comment: If you want a resizable, array-like structure made up of characters, you should start with `std::string`. If for some reason you can't use `std::string`, you need to A) use dynamic allocation. B) manually keep track of when the allocation is about to fill up. C) make a new allocation that is larger. D) copy the characters in the old allocation to the new allocation. E) free the old allocation F) use the new allocation going forward until it's full and then go back to B.

Answer (score 2):

> Size of my char array automatically shrinks to 1 after calling a
> function

It is the size of an object of the type `char`.

The parameters of the function have referenced types to objects of the type `char`.

```
void getinput(char &first,char &second);
```

That is it is not a referenced type to a one-dimensional array.

So this call

```
getinput(a[60],b[60]);
```

passes to the function references to non-existent scalar elements of two arrays at the index equal to `60`.

A simple way to declare the function is the following

```
void getinput( char *first,char *second );
```

and the function can be called like

```
getinput( a, b );
```

If you want to have a referenced type for the parameters then the function can be declared like

```
void getinput(char ( &first )[60], char ( &second )[60] );
```

and called like

```
getinput( a, b );
```

Pay attention to that in the both cases of the function declaration it is unsafe because there is no check in statements like this

```
cin >> first;
```

whether the user wrote outside the arrays.

Instead of using the operator >> you could apply the member function `getline`.

For example

```
std::cin.getline( first, 60 );
```

Comment: If the arrays decay to `char*`, how would reading from `std::cin` into the pointers work though?

Comment: @J.Schultke This operator is specially defined for objects of the type char *  and it is supposed that it will read a string in a character array.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
cout << a[60] << "   l     " << b[60] <<endl;
```

This line doesn't write an array to `std::cout`, it only writes a single element to `std::cout`, namely the 61st (which is actually outside of your array).

Instead, you should do this:

```cpp
std::cout << a << "   l     " << b << '\n';
```

Also note that you `getinput(char&, char&)` function will only read two characters in total from the stream, not two arrays. I recommend implementing the whole thing using `std::string` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << "   l     " << b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The signature of `getinput` is also wrong.

Comment: @Botje The signature may be correct.  The OP may want to use single characters instead of an array.  Perfectly reasonable if the inputs are single characters.

Comment: Quoting from the question text: "i can input more then one character [and the output] automatically shrinks down in size to one character."